# Select records in table using 2 parameters

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I am in need of some guidance on how to query a database table and find whether a person has voted on an item already by ip address. 
I have a table that stores set_id, ip_address, and vote. Once the person votes, it shows a message that says they already voted. This will be done with an `If` statement.

I have two methods that I have tried in the controller:

```
$setDao->getRatingByIp($ipAdress);
```

I am requesting this with:

```
$ipAddress = $this->_request->getClientIp();
```

In the SQL query, it returns the ip address but I have no way to get the set_id.

Here is the function in the model:

```
public function getRatingByIp($ipAddress)
{
    $sql = "SELECT ip_address FROM " . $this->_prefix . " media_set_rating WHERE set_id = " . $ipAddress);
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    return mysql_num_rows($result);
}
```

The second that I tried was an array:

```
$ip = array();
    $ip['set_id'] = $setId;
    $ip['ip_address'] = $ipAddress;     
    $setDao->getRatingByIp($ip);
```

I think this may work, but I am unsure how to implement it in the query above. I have tried several arrangements, but they all return nothing when I do an SQL check `echo $sql; exit;`

Updated May 29th 11:28pm EST

Here is the entire (widget) controller:

```
    protected function _prepareShow() 
{
    $setId  = $this->_request->getParam('set_id');
    $rating = $this->_request->getParam('rating');
    $grades = $this->_request->getParam('grades');
    $pageUrl      = $this->_request->getPathInfo();
    $ipAddress = $this->_request->getClientIp();
    $limit = 3;

    $conn = XXX_Db_Connection::factory()->getSlaveConnection();
    $setDao = XXX_Model_Dao_Factory::getInstance()->setModule('media')->getSetDao();
    $setDao->setDbConnection($conn);



    $ip = array();
    $ip['set_id'] = $setId;
    $ip['ip_address'] = $ipAddress;

    $setDao->getRatingByIp($ip);

    $grades = $setDao->gradeRound($setId);

    if ($this->_request->isPost('rating')) {



        $rating = new Media_Models_Set(array(
            'set_id'       => $this->_request->getPost('setId'),
            'ip_address'   => $this->_request->getClientIp(),
            'rating'       => $this->_request->getPost('rating'),
        ));

        $setDao->rate($rating);

        $ratings = new Media_Models_Set(array(
            'set_id'       => $this->_request->getPost('setId'),
            'rating'       => $this->_request->getPost('rating'),
            'grades'       => $this->_request->getPost('grades'),
        ));

        $setDao->averageRating($ratings);

        $flashMessenger = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('FlashMessenger');
        $flashMessenger->addMessage($this->_view->translator()->widget('send_rating_success'));

        $redirector = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('Redirector');
        $redirector->gotoUrl($this->_view->APP_URL . $pageUrl . '#rateForm');
    }
    $this->_view->assign('ip', $ip);
    $this->_view->assign('set_id', $setId);
    $this->_view->assign('rating', $rating);
    $this->_view->assign('grades', $grades);
}
```

The array was left in there as my last attempt to pass the information.

Updated May 31st 2013

I now have a solution that works. I had been throwing code at this for several days and finally i realized a couple of things. One was i never had the set_id to begin with. I was requesting it but it was not done in the proper fashion. The other was that i was including setId in the view and did not need to do that. The below code that Orangpill suggested i believe will work now that i have the set_id. However i took a different  approach. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: I still doesn't understand what really do you want to. In your query you user this set_id = $ipAddress, which information do you have in set_id? Whay are you comparing with ip address? Other thing that I notice is in this code `$setDao->getRatingByIp($ip);` you should use this instead: `$setDao->getRatingByIp($ip['ip_address');` or even `$setDao->getRatingByIp($ipAddress);`

Comment: By the way, what do you want is really not clear. Try be more specific.

Comment: That is my issue. i do not know how to add both ip_address and set_id to the string in the controller so that i have use of them in the module. That is why i tried the array. {$setDao->getRatingByIp($ipAddress);} is what i originally used i get that from here {$ipAddress = $this->_request->getClientIp();}

Comment: I just want to be able to select a record if it exists by set_id and ip_address so that they will not be able to vote more than once. In the controller i have both of these parameters and i need to know how to use them to pass the information to the model to get the record.

Comment: so, do you need something like this? `select * from table where ipaddress - $ip and set_id = $set_id`?

Comment: That would be the easiest but how do i get that info from the controller. I also tried something like this in the controller $setDao->getRatingByIp($setId, $ipAddress); but could not figure out how to call it in the model.

Comment: Well, thare are a lot of possibilities. But, you need figure out where do you have this information. The set_id is send by POST? It`s a SESSION value? Where this information come from?

Comment: set_id is a post and also controller knows it because it uses it to get the set. The ip address is here in controller $ipAddress = $this->_request->getClientIp(); I have both and can get one at a time in the model just not both. ip_address is a post also as both of them are put in the table by the controller. via another function if it will help i can post the whole controller for you.

Comment: what kind of object is setDao? Does it extend from a base Zend Library Component?

Comment: Yes it is a custom connection controller. So it is extended from that and that extends Zend.

Comment: so a child of Zend_Db_Adapter?  Is there a reason the setId can't be passed into the getRatingByIp controller?

Comment: getRatingByIp is not the controller. It is a part of the controller. yes it can be passed to it. I am struggling on how to pass both of them - set_id and ip_address and then how to implement that in the query.

Comment: i will add the controller to the top so you can see the whole thing.

Comment: I have posted the resolution above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the changes in the controller:

```
$setId  = $this->_request->getParam('set_id', 1); I added the 1.
```

I used this method to pass the 2 parameters to the model

```
        $params = new Media_Models_Set(array(
        'set_id'       => $setId,
        'ip_address'   => $this->_request->getClientIp(),
    ));

    $param = $setDao->getRatingByIp($params);
```

Then i added param to the view

```
$this->_view->assign('param', $param);
```

In the model i used this method for query

```
     public function getRatingByIp($params) 
 {       
    $sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM " . $this->_prefix . "media_set_rating
                    WHERE set_id = '%s' and ip_address = '%s'",
                    mysql_real_escape_string((int)$params->set_id),
                    mysql_real_escape_string($params->ip_address));
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    return mysql_num_rows($result);
 }
```

Then finally in the view i added an if statement to go against the count.

```
 <?php if ($this->param > 0) : ?>
 <div class="grid_12"><div class="message"><?php echo $this->translator()->widget('already_voted'); ?></div></div>
 <?php else: ?>
 Rate form goes here!
 <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding the problem but could it be as easy as:

```
public function hasPersonVoted($ipAddress, $setId)
{
    $sql = "select * as qty from ".
           "from `".$this->_prefix."media_set_rating` ".
           "where set_id=".mysql_real_escape_string($setId)." and ".
                 "ip_address = ".mysql_real_escape_string($ipAddress);
    $res = mysql_query($sql);
    return mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
}
```

If nothing is found it should return a false
if Something is found it should return the row which would be truthy in a comparison.

I am making an assumption that $this is an extended controller as per the comments.
If it is an extended table object you could use `return $this->getAdapter()->fetchAll($sql);`

Comment: What would you put in the controller to initiate this? $setDao->getRatingByIp($setId, $ipAddress); I am unsure about what $db->quote is doing.

Comment: quote sanitizes and quotes a variable to guard against injection... the usage would be $setDao->hasPersonVoted($ipAddress, $setId); and it would return either a false or the record that shows their vote as an associative array. (which would evaluate to true in an array)

Comment: updated the answer assuming the this is not a Zend_Db_Adapter Instance... this will get the default adapter that was set up in your bootstrap to get at the table.

Comment: I tried what you have and the sql returns this - Fatal error: Call to a member function quote() on a non-object

Comment: Okay ... couple of framing questions... what version of Zend Framework are you using 1.x or 2.x? Are you configuring a db resource in your bootstrap? are you using mysql_* functions in lieu of the standard Zend_Db classes?

Comment: Zend 1.x db resource is configured elsewhere not in bootstrap. app.ini holds db information. yes using functions.

Comment: This is a huge site and everything is working on it It is almost complete. So it is unlikely that the db or other components are not working. For instance i can successfully rate a set and put all info into both tables holding rating for set and set_id with Ip_address in the other table.

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out what's the best way to get at an instance of the db adapter that can connect to the media_set_rating table. also fyi info on quote is [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.adapter.html)

Comment: If you can set the $db property to a object that contains `Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract` somewhere in it's lineage and is connected to the table in question then the above code should work. If you where using the standard Zend DB Bootstraping then adding `resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true` to the resource definition in the ini should make the above code work.

Comment: I do not have to call a db connection before doing a query. It is live in the controller and live in the model. When i do this in the controller: $ipAddress = $this->_request->getClientIp(); $setDao->getRatingByIp($ipAddress); it gives me the ipAddress passed to the model. I do not have to use $ipAddress in the model i can use $ip it doesnt care as long as the same is used in the ip_address = ". $ip . This returns the ip address for me. if i change in the controller to be setId then set id will show up in its place. i cannot for some reason grasp getting both.

Comment: I think i tried this already but will give it a try again. i have been at it so long i dont remember what i have and have not done

Comment: This only returns one of the parameters. It uses the first param that is in the string as the variable. Getting late i will go back to this tomorrow. feel free to leave other comments i will get them in the morning.

Comment: I have posted the resolution above.